# Why Cursor lost sort DESC of sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got a query in sqlite

```
String[] args = { Report_DATETIME,Report_DATETIME, EMSUnitCode };
            String sql = "Select * from TR_ReportingAll Where  (Report_DATETIME<? or ( Report_DATETIME=? and EMSUnitCode!=?)) order by Report_DATETIME,EMSUnitCode DESC Limit 10";
            mCursor = database.rawQuery(sql, args);
```

Why values of mCursor is ASC? When i get mCursor.moveToNext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort criteria is `Report_DATEIME ASC` and then, all items with equal Report_DATEIME are sorted by `EMSUnitCode DESC`. `DESC` does not apply to all `ORDER BY` fields, but only those you set them for and `ASC` is default order if not specified otherwise. Therefore if you want to date to be descending change your order to `order by Report_DATETIME DESC,EMSUnitCode DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Your results are ordered by `Report_DATETIME ASC` first, then for any identical `Report_DATETIME` by `EMSUnitCode DESC` second.